# How can i get string value from db which sets integer for server-side processing?

Tags: php, ajax, server

I'm using a Datatables example and I want to get string value for the gender: 
'**Male**' or '**Female**' instead of **1** or **2**.

My **config.php** code for gender:

```
$gender = [1 => "Male", "Female"];
```

And this is my server-processing.php code which returns integer:

`array( 'db' => 'gender',   'dt' => 4)`.

Who can help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common issue, I do this:

Create and array with the gender strings in array positions 1 and 2.

```
$genders = array('','Male', 'Female');

$gender = $genders[$genderValue];
```

Where `$genderValue` equals either 1 for male or 2 for female.